# How to get router WiFi SSID?

Tags: wifi, upnp, ssid

How I can get the router WiFi SSID?

It is possible to use UPNP, but WFADevice has no any state variables or methods for SSID.

There is the method - GetAPSettings, which is possible can return some info, including SSID, but it requires input parameter 'NewMessage' to be taken, and I can't find what I must set for it.